# Prevent RawSQL injection in Django

Tags: python, sql, django, django-rest-framework, rawsql

In my Django application I am using RawSQL queries as an additional security layer, I  want to parse every RawSQL query to prevent delete or update operation.

example : There are some automated jobs scheduled from django admin panel which utilise the RawSQL queries while execution I need a method to add a validation layer over the rawsql execution so that I can prevent execution of any delete, update etc queries.

Comment: Why use raw sql queries in the first place? This is one of the main features of Django's orm, to prevent writing raw queries.

Comment: At some places we need functionality that is highly dynamic and changes rapidly as we perform a/b testing for that purpose we use rawsql queries do you know any way in which we can use django queries in dynamic manner ?

Comment: Django's orm is often more easy to adapt than raw queries, especially if the fields/types of a model can change.